# Will the EPL license apply to my runnable jar (my independent code + auto genarated eclipse code)?

Tags: license-compatibility, epl

I have one class named Count.java and is independent, not using any eclipse libraries.
I am trying to create a **runnable** **jar** out of it.

While doing so I see that following eclipse package is created
**(org\eclipse\jdt\internal\jarinjarloader)**

so basically the output jar contains

```
Generated x.jar file structure is

com
  |_din
     |_util
         |_Count.class //Not a derivative work of eclipse.

META-INF
  |_MANIFEST.MF

org        //autogenerated by eclipse 
  |_eclipse
     |_jdt
        |_internal
            |_jarinjarloader
                 |_JarRsrcLoader$ManifestInfo.class
                 |_JarRsrcLoader.class 
                 |_JIJConstants.class    
                 |_RsrcURLConnection.class
                 |_RsrcURLStreamHandler.class 
                 |_RsrcURLStreamHandlerFactory.class
```

Clearly the generated eclipse package is covered under **eclipse public license 1.0**
and 
Clearly my code is not a derivative work of eclipse.

My question:

Can I release my overall license of the jar as my own proprietary jar?

Closest references found is

1. https://eclipse.org/legal/eplfaq.php#PROPPROD

Other closest reference are

2. https://eclipse.org/legal/eplfaq.php#MODULEDIST

Regarding derivative work

3. https://eclipse.org/legal/eplfaq.php#DERIV
4. https://eclipse.org/legal/eplfaq.php#LINK
5. https://eclipse.org/legal/eplfaq.php#EXAMPLE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the context correctly, I used the Eclipse IDE to create a Java project and used Eclipse's ["Runnable JAR File Exporter"](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-export-runnable-jar.htm) to export my project as a self-runnable Jar. As a result of this process, the exported Jar contains both my own original code and additional Eclipse binary code injected by Eclipse to support the self running feature. The [source](http://git.eclipse.org/c/jdt/eclipse.jdt.ui.git/plain/org.eclipse.jdt.ui/jar%20in%20jar%20loader/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/jarinjarloader/RsrcURLStreamHandler.java) of an example of injected code is licensed under the EPL-1.0.

The question is then: what are my obligations in this context?

The EPL is generally considered as a "limited copyleft" license with fairly simple [requirements](https://enterprise.dejacode.com/license_library/Demo/epl-1.0/#license-requirements) as detailed in [Section 3](http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html) in particular Section 3.iv:

> iv) states that source code for the Program is available from such Contributor, and informs licensees how to obtain it in a reasonable manner on or through a medium customarily used for software exchange.

The gist of it is that a redistribution of unmodified compiled object code (e.g. the class files injected in the Jar) would just require you to provide some credits, disclaimers and a link to were to get the corresponding source code, in this case from the upstream Eclipse project(s).

To further understand the spirit of the EPL, here is a [commentary](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/epl-discuss/msg00107.html) from the [Executive Director](http://www.eclipse.org/org/foundation/staff.php) of the Eclipse Foundation:

> [...] the EPL 1.0 was always intended to be a weak copyleft license. It was drafted such that anything which is *not* a derivative work could be offered under whatever terms the copyright holder desired. [...]

Here having some unmodified EPL-licensed classes included in a Jar is clearly something I would consider as a side-by-side redistribution and not a derivative work.